# how to hide the status bar from all layouts?

Tags: android

I want to hide the statusbar from all layouts on click of button.That button i have define in setting layout. But on click of hide button the status bar of current layout is getting hide but on other layout is unaffected.So let me know how to implement it on all the layouts of mu app.

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a superclass for all Activities, call it something like BaseActivity or AbstractActivity and make each activity extend this class
2. In the onCreate, before `setContentView`, read from a database like SharedPreferences whether the status bar should be hidden. If so, then hide it.
3. In your Settings activity, call `recreate()` so that each onCreate from the previous activities are called again.

Comment: This actually should be on top.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the version of android you are using. For example in Android 4.0 and lower you can achieve it by doing:

```
<application
...
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
...
</application>
```

For full documentation go to: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status

Edit: What would be better for your button is this code:

```
void HideStatusBar() {
     View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
     // Hide the status bar.
     int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
     decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
     // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
     // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
     ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
     actionBar.hide();
}
```

So, when the user clicks the button call this function. Remember this also hides the action bar or toolbar, so if you don't want that remove the `actionbar.hide()` part. It's nice, but unfortunately, it only works on Android 4.1 and higher, so if you are supporting lower versions too better look at the documentation for clues. Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How doesn't it?

Comment: `But on click of hide button the status bar of current layout is getting hide but on other layout is unaffected.` does your question answer this?

Comment: The documentation is there and also using this function as a static one in another class, we can do the same.

Comment: so in short, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: well, guess so.

Comment: @zun..no i want to make it happen on button click and it should get implement on all my layouts of app

Comment: I understand you should create a base activity and then extend it, as @zammy said. In the onCreate() method call this, and basically, it would happen on every single open activity.